# When is it preferred to combine Add/Edit functionality, and when to keep them separate?

Tags: coding-style

I regularly come across situations where I need to Add or Edit an item, and sometimes I use separate methods for Add and Edit, and other times I combine them into a single method.

Is one method preferred over the other? If so, why?

```
public void AddItem()
{
    ShowEditingPopup(new Item(), "Add Item");
}

public void EditItem(Item item)
{
    ShowEditingPopup(item, "Edit Item");
}
```

OR

```
public void EditItem(Item item)
{
    ShowEditingPopup(
        (item ?? new Item()), 
        string.format("{0} Item", (item == null ? "Add " : "Edit "))
    );
}
```

where `ShowEditingPopup` is defined as

```
public void ShowEditingPopup(object popupDataContext, string popupTitle)
{
    PopupDataContext = popupDataContext;
    PopupTitle = popupTitle;
    IsPopupVisible = true;
}
```

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I am not Saving the item, I am opening it for Editing. I almost always implement a generic Save method for saving to the database

**Edit #2:** Edited code samples so they more accurately reflect the sort of situation I am referring to

Comment: Minor quibble - if you are going to combine, use a proper name for the method `EditOrAddItem`, instead of just `EditItem`.

Comment: @Oded I just use SaveItem ... it applies for both.

Comment: @AJC - fair enough. However, the example still has `EditItem`.

Comment: More of a matter of choice than anything else....Will like to see the answers though

Comment: @Oded Yeah this isn't my actual code, it's just an example. I drew a blank as to what to name the combined method so I just went with `EditItem`

Comment: Is it just me or was a very similar question asked recently? I can't find it by searching... anyone else think this is familiar?

Comment: @AJC Just to clarify, I'm not looking to Save the item. In the code that prompted me to post this question, there are Add and Edit buttons, and both of them opens a popup with either a new item, or an existing item for editing.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner There was a recent one, but it dealt with saving changes to a repository, in which case I think a `Save` method is perfectly valid http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/104404/1130

Answer (score 2):

Think about your context for a second... There is no distinction between Adding a new element or editing an existing one. You just `SaveChanges()`. The individual element state tell the context whether its a new element being added or an existing one being edited.

EDIT: Ok... Well in that case, I do have separate Controller Actions (MVC3) for each action, however, only 1 view...

Comment: I am not saving the object, I am opening it in a new window for Editing. (I do have a generic `Save` method for saving the object back to the database though)

Comment: @Rachel view edit...

Comment: This question was prompted because the code I am working with usually calls `ShowPopup(popupContent, popupTitle);`, and I was curious if there was a reason to create separate calls showing a new item or an existing item, or to do both in the same method.

Comment: @Rachel I can't find a reason not to combine the calls... However it is a personal choice... If you want to keep them separated or mix them. Like I said, in my case, I use separate calls, but the same UI for both.

Comment: +1 for different actions but same view. Think of the sites that you visit that have the best usability..most of them use the same screen for creating/editing items, unless there are very specific business conditions enabled/shown when doing either action.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of how well you understand *Single Responsibility Principle*. It would be more *cleaner* and *easier* to read, understand, and maintain if the responsibilities are decoupled in to seperate methods/actions. However, this from the coding perspective.

If I had to pick one approach out of your examples, I would go for the *first* approach.

The user's perspective depends on how easy is to add new item or edit an existing item (number of clicks is one way I measure) and probably to follow few golden rules.

If I had to implement the functionality (UI/Form), I would have a single form when add and edit both have same fetures, and two seperate forms when they differ.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I'm adding or editing a `Person` entity.  I would almost always have two models to handle the add/edit processes:

- `AddPersonModel`
- `EditPersonModel`

They would almost always inherit from a common abstract base class:

- `AddEditPersonModelBase`

So the base class might have an abstract `Commit` method, which the derived classes override in order to either new up a new `Person` entity, or to save the changes to the existing `Person` entity.

The business logic that's common to both adding and editing goes in the base class (for instance, for editing addresses), but there's always a little bit of business logic that's different if you're adding or editing, and those go in the subclasses.  For instance, you might want to assign them a unique incrementing ID number, but you don't actually create it until you save the entity.  In that case, only your `EditPersonModel` has that property.

Similarly, you'd have separate Views (and ViewModels) for adding or editing a `Person`, but it would make sense to have both add and edit variants inherit from the same base class because a lot of it would be common.

Comment: In this case, and in most cases I have done recently, both Adding and Editing use the exact same form. I am using `WPF` / `MVVM`, and the UI is a generic DataTemplate for the object, while the ViewModel for the object knows how to handle it based on it's state.

Comment: @Rachel - in MVVM parlance, you either new up an `AddPersonViewModel` (which doesn't take a `Person` in the constructor) or an `EditPersonViewModel` (which does take an existing `Person` in the constructor).  Whichever one gets created gets set as the `Window`'s `DataContext`.  When WPF sees one of those in the layout, it goes looking for a `DataTemplate` for that `ViewModel` and applies it automatically. Both `AddPersonViewModel` and `EditPersonViewModel` inherit from a common base class with the common logic between them in it. For instance, an `ICommand` to save.  Save button binds to that.

Comment: @Rachel - You can have a common `DataTemplate` that binds to either the add or edit `ViewModel` (by binding to the base class), or you can add a new `DataTemplate` that binds to a child class, if one or both need to have different Views.

Comment: Usually I just have a `PersonViewModel` which accepts a `Person` object in the constructor. I usually create small apps and often don't see a need for separate `Views`/`ViewModels` unless there is a large difference between a new object and an existing one. It is that kind of situation that prompted my question.

Answer (score 0):

I personally tend to follow the principals of being **semantic**. This means that I usually don't provide a all-in-one edit form. In other words, users usually don't want to edit the entire information of an **entity**. Rather their edit process is more semantic and can be classified. For example, for **user entity**, people usually **edit passwords** and **edit profile**. Thus, I make two functions for edit like:

```
public bool EditPassword(string userName)
{
    // code here
}

public bool EditProfile(Profile newProfile)
{
    // code here    
}
```

Or, users usually edit an article in these ways:

```
public bool PutArticleIntoCategories(int articleId, List<Category> categories)
{

}

public bool EditArticleSummary(int articleId, string newSummary)
{

}
```

In brief, I usually create a all-in-one creation form, but I tend to use small, chunked edit forms for each semantic edit operation. Thus, I usually don't merge them. However, this doesn't mean that you can't merge them. Whenever you want to provide a fat, big edit form which resembles creation form, I think merging can work better.